# Cannot parse to get the token

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

For some reason I cannot get the token from the localstorage in order to make the request, it says that there is no token. I am using cookie parser. I am trying to create a new category for my shop. It is not recognizing the token, although it is here.

here is my client:

adminDashoard.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { createCategory } from './api/category';
import isEmpty from 'validator/lib/isEmpty';
import { showErrorMsg, showSuccessMsg } from './helpers/message';
import { showLoading } from './helpers/Loading'



export default function AdminDashboard() {
const [category, setCategory] = useState('');
const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('');
const [successMsg, setSuccessMsg] = useState('');
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const handleMessages= evt =>{
    setErrorMsg('');
    setSuccessMsg('');
}

const handleCategoryChange = (evt) => {
    setErrorMsg('');
    setSuccessMsg('');
    setCategory(evt.target.value);
   

}
const handleCategorySubmit = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();



    if (isEmpty(category)) {

        setErrorMsg('Please enter a category')
    } else {
        const data = { category }

        setLoading(true);
        createCategory(data)
            .then(response => {
                setLoading(false);
                setSuccessMsg(response.data.successMessage)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setLoading(false);
                setErrorMsg(err.response.data.errorMessage)
                console.log(err)
            })

    }


};



function ShowHeader() {
    return (
        <div className='bg-dark text-white py-4'>
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-md-6'>
                        <h1>
                            <i className='fas fa-home'>   Dashboard</i>
                        </h1>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

function ShowActionBtns() {
    return (
        <div className='bg-light my-2'>
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='row pb-3'>
                    <div className='col-md-4 my-1 '>
                        <button
                            className='btn btn-outline-info btn-block'
                            data-toggle='modal'
                            data-target='#addCategoryModal'>
                            <i className=' fas fa-plus'>Add Category</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-md-4 my-1 '>
                        <button className='btn btn-outline-danger btn-block'>
                            <i className=' fas fa-plus'>Add Products</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-md-4 my-1 '>
                        <button className='btn btn-outline-success btn-block'>
                            <i className=' fas fa-plus'>Add Blog</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

function ShowCategoryModal() {
    return (
        <div id='addCategoryModal' className='modal' onClick={handleMessages}>
            <div className='modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg'>
                <div className='modal-content'>
                    <form onSubmit={handleCategorySubmit}>

                        <div className='modal-header bg-info text-white'>
                            <h5 className='modal-title'>Add Category</h5>
                            <button className='close' data-dismiss='modal'>
                                <span>
                                    <i className='fas fa-times'></i>
                                </span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div className='modal-body my-2'>
                            {errorMsg && showErrorMsg(errorMsg)}
                            {successMsg && showSuccessMsg(successMsg)}
                            {
                                loading ? (
                                    <div className='text-center'>{showLoading()}</div>
                                ) : (
                                    <>
                                        <label className='text-secondary'> Category</label>
                                        <input
                                            type='text'
                                            className='form-control'
                                            name='category'
                                            value={category}
                                            onChange={handleCategoryChange}
                                        />
                                    </>
                                )
                            }


                        </div>

                        <div className='modal-footer'>
                            <button data-dismiss='modal' className='btn btn-secondary'>Close</button>
                            <button className='btn btn-info' type='submit'>Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

return <div>
    {ShowHeader()}
    {ShowActionBtns()}
    {ShowCategoryModal()}
</div>
    }
```

Here is my api file:

```
import axios from "axios"

export const createCategory = async (formData) => {
const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       
    },
    
};

const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/category', formData, config);
return response;
```

}

on the server side,

```
  here is my server.js : 
  const express=require('express');
  const app= express();
  const cors=require('cors');
  const connectDB= require('./database/db');
  const morgan= require('morgan');
  const authRoutes= require ('./routes/auth')
  const categoryRoutes = require ('./routes/category');
  const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

  //middleware
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);
  app.use('/api/category', categoryRoutes);

  connectDB();

  const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

  app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

  app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
  res.send(' hello server')
    })
```

here is my route file :

```
  const express = require('express');
  const router = express.Router();
  const categoryController = require('../routes/controllers/category');
  const  {authenticatateJWT} = require('./middleware/authenticator');

  router.post('/', authenticatateJWT, categoryController.create);

  module.exports = router;
```

here is my controller:

```
    exports.create = (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.user);

    setTimeout(() =>{
    res.json({
      successMessage: `${req.body.category} was created!`
      });
      }, 5000)

      }
```

here is my middleware:

```
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    const { jwtSecret } = require('../../config/keys');

    exports.authenticatateJWT = (req, res, next) => {
     const token = req.cookies.token;
     console.log(token);
     if (!token) {
     return res.status(401).json({
        errorMessage: 'No token. Authorization denied',
       });
    }
       try {
       const decoded = jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret);

       req.user = decoded.user;
       next();
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('jwt error:', err)
          res.status(401).json({
          errorMessage: 'Invalid token',

          });
      }
    };
```

Comment: You mention localstorage, but the code uses cookies. Also, there is no place in the code you've posted that would send the token to the client. Where does the client get the token?

Comment: actually the token is stored in the localstorage I have a seperate file for it. I am getting this error "uncaught (in promise) TypeError: err.response is undefined
    handleCategorySubmit AdminDashboard.js:38".